# show a picker after a button press event

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

Hi everyone, I am working on a crossplatform app that will allow the user to select first from a list.view and then from a picker. the listview works fine, and now I am working on the picker but I have run into a problem.

I have seem the implementation "picker.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) => " used to handle the selection of a new element on the list but I am having an issue with the sender on this. the error is "Error CS0136 A local or parameter named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter."

I understand that this error is related to the parameter sender from the even handler parameter in the func itself but since I am not declaring a new variable sender, how is this throwing an error? below is the code ( just a mock for now. this is the basic implementation but the content of the picker will change depending on what was selected on the listview.)

```
private void Button_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Picker picker = new Picker
        {
            Title = "Select SubUnit",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

       string[] list = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" } ;


        foreach(string subunit in list)
        {
            picker.Items.Add(subunit);
        }

        picker.Focus();

        picker.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (picker.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
              //ToDo. Prob unnecessary to handle.
            }
            else
            {
                string selectedSub = picker.Items[picker.SelectedIndex];
            }
        };

    }
```

I expect the picker to come into focus and allow the user to select an element after the button is pressed. any ideas?

right now, the only error is the syntax error I get on the sender object, and technically the picker not coming into focus but I am sure I can figure that one out once I get this to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are already using `sender` in the current scope

```
private void Button_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

you need to renamed the other instance of `sender` to something unique

```
picker.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, args) =>
```

Comment: yep, I had a feeling it would be something simple like that.